# Erro com WTFORMS FLASK.. já conferi várias vezes

Tags: python, flask

Preciso criar uma questão com resposta de múltipla escolha, mas na hora de fazer os formulários das respostas, tento criar um botão mas só aparece o código em Python na página, em vez de aparecer o botão, ou `bool`, o que seja.

Código python:

```py
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import SubmitField
class resposta(FlaskForm):
   a = SubmitField("a")
@app.route("/questions/<question>", methods=["POST"])
def questions(question):
    answer = resposta
    return render_template("questions.html", question=question, answer=answer)
```

código HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Questions</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1><p>Question {{question}}  </p></h1>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <div class="checkbox>">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" href="#">{{answer.a}}</button>
</div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

e na hora que eu inicio o programa e vou até a página,
em vez de aparecer o form formatado, só aparece o código Python assim:

```
<UnboundField(SubmitField, ('a',), {})>
```